# Is there a better way?

Tags: python

I have file say `abc.txt` with below format:

```
+ : @group2 : ALL  
+ : @grp_xvz : ALL  
+ : @group_abc_app: ALL  
+ : @group_1_abc : ALL  
+ : @group_2_xyz : ALL  
+ : @group_3_def@@nmo_hosts : ALL
```

I need to grep for specific entries and check if file size of abc.txt > 220

```
+ : @group_2_xyz : ALL   or 
+ : @group_3_def@@nmo_hosts : ALL   
and  filesize of abc.txt > 220
```

In bash I can do like this

```
if grep --quiet "+[[:blank:]]:[[:blank:]]@group_2_xyz[[:blank:]]*:[[:blank:]]ALL" abc.txt   
||  
 grep --quiet +[[:blank:]]:[[:blank:]]@group_3_def[@A-Za-z0-9_][[:blank:]]:[[:blank:]] abc.txt   
and                                                   
[ du -sb abc.txt | awk '{print $1}' -gt 220 ]; then  

..do..something
```

How to do same in python? I was trying to use "re.findall' but not sure if I can use multiple conditions there ? or if someone can suggest best way?

```
re.findall(r'+\s*:\s*@group_2_xyz\s*:\s*ALL', open('abc.txt,'r').read())
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks Ponnarasu for helping to cleanup the formatting. Appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os, re

match = re.search(
    r'^\+ *: *(@group_2_xyz|@group_3_def@@nmo_hosts) *: *ALL$',
    open('abc.txt').read(), re.M
    )

print(os.stat('abc.txt').st_size > 220, match is not None)
```

Comment: @bob. If you found the answer useful, please consider accepting it (i.e. click on the tick marker).

Comment: Thank  you Ekhumoro!  Sorry I am new here,  so it  will take some time to adjust.